# Retrieve orderid to check with the incoming order id whether it's present or not?

Tags: magento-1.9, php, database, orders, sales-order

I am totally new to magento and I have orderid. Now I have to check whether it exists or not.I am not aware of what class and method should be used for this.

Thanks In Advance...

Answer (score 2):

If you have the order entity id you can try the following:

```
$order = Mage::getModel('sales/order')->load($orderId);
if ($order->getIncrementId()) {
    // order exists
}
```

If you have the order increment id you'll need to use the following code:

```
$order = Mage::getModel('sales/order')->loadByIncrementId($orderIncrementId);
if ($order->getOrderId()) {
    // order exists
}
```